# Cannot connect to the database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, mdf

I have created a database in `App_Data` and I want to use this file in my project.

In the toolbar I grabbed the `sqlDatasource`. I clicked on `Configure data source`. I chose Microsoft SQL Server database file and said continue. I browsed for the file. I chose it then I clicked ok. The following error occurred:

I says the database myweb.mdf cannot be opened because it is version 661 and the server version is 662 and earlier: create database is aborted. The attempt to attached an auto-named database for the `\app-data\myweb.mdf` failed. A database with the same name exists or specified file cannot be opened or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: When and where did you create a database, you may want to take a look a post here http://rusanu.com/2010/11/23/this-server-supports-version-662-and-earlier/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 Whilst the database was created in SQL Server 2008, seems you need to upgrade the database using the **database migration wizard**

see [this answer for a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrent-version-661)

Comment: I dont have sql server running before

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [SQL Server: Attach incorrect version 661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrent-version-661)

You'll have to either upgrade your 2008 SP2 instance to R2, or you have to copy out the data in that database into an 2008 database (eg using the data migration wizard, or something equivalent).