# problem in connecting the database

Tags: asp.net

When I try to connect to the database I got the following error

> The database myweb.mdf cannot be opened because the version is 661. The server version is 662 or earlier. the downgrade is not supported by c/user/mydocuments/visual studio 2010/app-data/myweb.mdf create data is aborted. An attempt to an auto database for file
>   c/user/mydocuments/visual studio 2010/app-data/myweb.mdf failed. A database with the same file exist or it cant be opened or located in the UNC Share.

How can I use sql server to open the database?

Comment: @Zan: You don't need the same version.. Just a newer server version than the database file.  Unfortunately, the version numbers in this case are NOT in sequence which is a bit misleading.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrent-version-661

Answer (score 0):

The message is a bit misleading.  It should really say something like "the database is version 661.  This server supports version 662, 655, and earlier than 655."

662 is the version of SQL Server 2008 SP2.  However, 661 is the version of SQL Server 2008 **R2**.

Basically, you are trying to load a database file generated with SQL 2008 R2 into a SQL Server 2008 instance.  This isn't going to work.

Which means you need to either upgrade your sql server instance to R2 or you have to downgrade the database to SQL 2008.

Read here for more information: http://rusanu.com/2010/11/23/this-server-supports-version-662-and-earlier/

The additional information makes sense, even if the actual message doesn't.