# The database cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server support version 655 and earlier

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: attach incorrent version 661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrent-version-661)

When I run my program on my computer everything goes fine.

When that same program I try to run from another computer I got this error:

"the database cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server support version 655 and earlier"

I have installed SQL Server Express 2008 R2 on both machine.

Any advice?

Comment: Please post your connection string as well as the server version of both machines SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')