# The database '[path\MDF file] cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I copied my project to my hosting server space and received the following message while trying to run it:

> The database '[path\MDF file] cannot be opened because it is version
>   661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Any suggestions? I imagine it has to do with me using SQL Server Express 2008 and the hosting provider isn't. If so, where do I go from here? Does SSE have scripts available for re-creating the tables, and in another version?

Comment: Your MDF file is newer than the version of SQL Server that's installed - that "downgrade path" is not supported by SQL Server. If you backup from a SQL Server **2008 R2** version, you can only restore to **2008 R2** (or **newer**) - but not to a **2008** version...

Comment: See: [Why a SQL Server database from a higher version cannot be restored onto a lower version](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Unable_to_Restore_Database_From_Backup.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: attach incorrect version 661](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661)

Answer (score 0):

Other than recreating the database from scratch using a SQL 2000 comparability level, 
I got nothing...

Comment: I only saw the 2005 tag not the 2008 one. I'm going to eye doctors next week.