# Database "cannot be opened because it is version 661" when attaching .mdf file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to attach MvcMusicStore.mdf to my .\SQLEXPRESS instance (sql server version 10.0.2531) in sql server 2008 R2 management studio. I got the db from this project:
http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/releases/view/67151

When i am trying to attach i am getting an error?:

```
The database 'C:\PROJECTS\CODEPLEX\TFS10\MVCSITEMAP\BRANCHES\3.1.0\SRC\MVCSITEMAPPROVIDER\MVCMUSICSTORE\APP_DATA\MVCMUSICSTORE.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
```

Do I need to upgrade my sql server or what else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL Server Express instance is version 2008 and the database is from 2008 R2.  You'll have to upgrade to SQL Server Express 2008 R2 to restore the database.  It doesn't matter that you are using the 2008 R2 version of Management Studio - the database instance needs to be updated as well.

See [SQL Server: Attach incorrect version 661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661)