# Use database 661 version with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: attach incorrect version 661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661)

I have sql server database which have 661 version. I have SQL Server 2008 . I wana to attach and use this database with SQL Server 2008. But when I trying to attach this database sql server write error something like this:

> Cant attach database 661 version because sql server support only 655 database version or much early.

- What I must to do wifh SQL Server 2008 for use that database version ?
- Maybe I must setup latest Service Pack fo sql server ?
- Maybe something more ?

Comment: Have you tried to do a *backup* in your source server (version 661) and use *restore* in your destination 2008 server?

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661/4258260#4258260) on stackoverflow

Comment: You can't. The database is SQL Server **2008R2** and it cannot be downgraded to SQL Server 2008. Period. You can a) install an SQL Server 2008 R2 and attach the db to it or 2) export the original database from the original SQL 2008R2 in CSV/txt and then import it in SQL 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Version 661 is SQL 2008 R2. You can't restore or attach files from R2 to a SQL 2008 (655) server.

If you can upgrade to SQL 2008 R2, do that. Otherwise you'll have to find some way to migrate the data (eg; SSIS)