# Version 661 cannot be opened, server supports 655 and earlier

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, version

I ran a project on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 express and it came up with this error:
Version 661 cannot be opened, server supports 655 and earlier. I do not know the steps to proceed to fix this problem. Does anyone have a possible solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: attach incorrect version 661](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661)

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this several times, on dbs attached by endusers. You're probably trying to deal with a 2008R2 db on a 2008 instance.

It doesn't help that the various Microsoft teams have mixed up the sequence of database version numbers

**661** is SQL2008R2

**655**, **662** is SQL2008SP2

Also note that the error messages can be confusing sometimes because you'd expect all versions of 2008R2 to have a higher number than versions of 2008. 
But sometimes they don't!