# ADO.NET Entity Data Model getting an error when Generating from .mdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

When adding an Entity Data Model to my project I choose

-> Generate from existing Database

-> New connection

-> Data source : Sql server Database file -> browse to the file .

when clicking ok I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

any ideas what could be the cause for this?

I've removed SQL server 2008 R2 and installed sql server 2008 express

now I get a different error concerning the Northwind sample database.

> ```
> The database '...' cannot be
> ```
>
> opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 662 and
>   earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>
> ```
> Could not open new database '...'. CREATE
> ```
>
> DATABASE is aborted.
>
> ```
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\.. failed. A
> ```
>
> database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I'm guessing I would of gotten this error with the SQL SERVER R2 installation if it would of been able to connected.

Comment: Does your SQL Express/Compact/LocalDB runs?

Comment: i have an SQL server 2008 R2 installed and running , 
iv'e installed sql server 2008 express as well because i understood 
that visual studio needs it to connected to a db. 
the server explorer in VS has no problem connecting to that Database.

Comment: on `Connection Properties` dialog, click `Advanced` and paste the bottom line starting in `Data Source=` here.

Comment: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NORTHWND.MDF";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661 for the new error

Comment: it seems that SQLExpress is only for work via VS , 
it does not seem to have a management studio of it's own
any ways i would still like to solve the original problem
i'm re installing R2 ,  
i think the Original problem was that my R2 installation Name instance was not SQLEXPRESS ..

Comment: That's not true. SQLExpress shoud work just like (stripped down version of) regular SQL Server.