# Cannot open database because of Version error

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error when I attempt the following actions in sequence.

1. Start Debugging.
2. Log in as a User.
3. Stop Debugging.
4. Clean Build
5. Without closing browser or logging out start Debugging again.
6. Attempt to Edit or Create or Update some database record.

If the user is not logged in or the browser is closed the error does not occur. I have even upgraded the SQL instance referring this [SQL Server: attach incorrect version 661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661).

```
The database 'C:\USERS\ME\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\PROJ1\PROJ1\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 662 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
    Could not open new database 'C:\USERS\ME\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\PROJ1\PROJ1\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
    An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\USERS\ME\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\PROJ1\PROJ1\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

I am testing this on Chrome.
Any Ideas on what area of either `MVC Code/ SQL/ Web.Config` I should look for to find the cause of this error. I haven't changed the default Membership that is created with VS2012 when you start a new project.

Comment: Do you have that DB open in the VS Server Explorer?

Comment: @Jack It is open in the database explorer.

Comment: Have you tried closing / detaching it?