# Attaching .mdf file error in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to attach a `.mdf` file in SQL Server 2005 and am getting this error:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\server\db\main.mdf", Operating system error 5: "5(error not found)", (Microsoft SQL server, Error: 5120)

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Is this SQL Server on your local machine, or on a remote one? Are you **sure** the `main.mdf` file is present in that location **on the server machine** (on the **remote** machine, if your SQL Server isn't running on your own PC)

Answer (score 0):

Run below query on "new query window" and get the service account name.

```
declare @sqlser varchar(20)
EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key='SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER',
@value_name='objectname', @value=@sqlser OUTPUT
PRINT 'Account Starting SQL Server Service:' +convert(varchar(30),@sqlser)
```

After getting the service-account (S/A) try the below steps to provide full privilege to files.

Step 1: Right click on the folder "" where the mdf and ldf files located and click on properties.

Step 2: Click on security tab.

Step 3: Click on Add button and add sql service account (S/A).

Step 4: Provide "Full control" privilege and click ok.

Step 5: Verify both mdf and ldf have modify privilege.

Step 6: Attach the db!

[source](http://www.mssqlfix.com/2013/05/unable-to-open-physical-file-operating.html)

Goto RUN
Type services.msc & press enter
In service control manager find the below service w.r.t to your edition.

**For SQL Server 2000**

`MSSQLSERVER` -- for default instance

`MSSQL$instancename` -- for named instance

**For SQL Server 2005 & SQL Server 2008**

`SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` -- for default instance

`SQL Server (instancename)` -- for named instance

Check the "Log On as" for the SQL service and provide modify privilege to that ID in the folder.

Comment: the query isn't working - getting this error: RegOpenKeyEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
Msg 22001, Level 1, State 1

Comment: declare @sqlser varchar(20)
EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key='SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER',
@value_name='objectname', @value=@sqlser OUTPUT
PRINT 'Account Starting SQL Server Service:' +convert(varchar(30),@sqlser)

Comment: hm wierd. I tried to attach the mdf by query   and am still getting the same error:  Unable to open the physical file "C:\MuServer\DB\MuOnline.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(error not found)".

Comment: I was able to run .bak from this folder before but now i cant run .mdf/ldf

Comment: wierd, getting this error now:  The database 'main' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 611 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

Comment: trying it with 2008 R2 instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257684/sql-server-attach-incorrect-version-661